# Trouble with SqlExceptions on Update Statement

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, jdbc-odbc

On update of any data of any of the field it giving error like:

> Driver loaded
>   statement is created
>
> java.sql.SQLException: General error
>   at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.createSQLException(JdbcOdbc.java:6986)
>   at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.standardError(JdbcOdbc.java:7114)
>   at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.SQLExecDirect(JdbcOdbc.java:3110)
>   at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcStatement.execute(JdbcOdbcStatement.java:338)
>               at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcStatement.executeUpdate(JdbcOdbcStatement.java:288)
>               at sanskarwani.updateREGISTRATION1(sanskarwani.java:2792)
>               at sanskarwani.access$700(sanskarwani.java:29)
>               at sanskarwani$8.actionPerformed(sanskarwani.java:1255)
>               at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1995)
>               at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2318)
>               at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:387)
>               at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:242)
>               at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:236)
>               at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(AWTEventMulticaster.java:272)
>               at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6038)
>               at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3260)
>               at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:5803)
>               at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2058)
>               at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4410)
>               at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2116)
>               at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4240)
>               at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4322)
>               at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:3986)
>               at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:3916)
>               at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2102)
>               at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2429)
>               at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4240)
>               at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:599)
>               at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:273)
>               at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:183)
>               at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:173)
>               at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:168)
>               at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:160)
>               at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:121)

My code is:

```
String nmreg = cbnm.getSelectedItem().toString();

if(nmreg.equals(""))   //{
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null," ENTER THE NAME ");

try
{
    Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
    System.out.println("\n Driver loaded");

    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:wanisamajDB");
    Statement stmt = con.createStatement();

    System.out.println("statement is created");

    String qry = " UPDATE Registration1 set RegistrationNo = '"+cbregn.getSelectedItem()+"',SeniorPerson = '"+cbnm.getSelectedItem()+"', NativePlace = '"+tfplace.getText()+"',Kul = '"+tfkul.getText()+"', Gotra = '"+tfgotra.getText()+"' ,KulSwami = '"+tfswami.getText()+"', ResidensialAddress = '"+taraddr.getText()+"' , PinCode = '"+tfpcd.getText()+"', STDcode = '"+tfstdcode.getText()+"',TelephoneNo = '"+tftele.getText()+"', MobileNo = '"+tfmno.getText()+"', Email = '"+tfemail.getText()+"',Website ='"+tfweb.getText()+"',Education ='"+tfedu.getText()+"',Branch ='"+tfbrch.getText()+"',BloodGroup ='"+cbbldgrp.getSelectedItem()+"' where SeniorPerson='" +cbnm.getSelectedItem().toString()+"'" ;
             // String qry= " UPDATE Registration1 set SeniorPerson = '"+cbnm.getSelectedItem().toString()+"',NativePlace = '"+tfplace.getText()+"', Kul = '"+tfkul.getText()+"',Gotra = '"+tfgotra.getText()+"' , KulSwami = '"+tfswami.getText()+"', ResidensialAddress = '"+taraddr.getText()+"' , PinCode = '"+Integer.parseInt(tfpcd.getText())+"', STDcode = '"+Integer.parseInt(tfstdcode.getText())+"',TelephoneNo = '"+Integer.parseInt(tftele.getText())+"',MobileNo = '"+Integer.parseInt(tfmno.getText())+"',Email = '"+tfemail.getText()+"',Website ='"+tfweb.getText()+"',Education ='"+tfedu.getText()+"',Branch ='"+tfbrch.getText()+"',BloodGroup ='"+cbbldgrp.getSelectedItem().toString()+"' where RegistrationNo='" +Integer.parseInt(cbregn.getSelectedItem().toString())+"'" ;
              stmt.executeUpdate(qry);
              JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"RECORD IS UPDATED SUCCESSFULLY ");
              System.out.println("QUERY");       

             // cbregn.setEditable(false);
              cbnm.setEditable(false);
              tfplace.setEditable(false);
              tfkul.setEditable(false);
              tfgotra.setEditable(false);
              tfswami.setEditable(false);
              taraddr.setEditable(false);
              tfpcd.setEditable(false);
              tfstdcode.setEditable(false);
              tftele.setEditable(false);
              tfmno.setEditable(false);
              tfemail.setEditable(false);
              tfweb.setEditable(false);
              tfedu.setEditable(false);
              tfbrch.setEditable(false);
              cbbldgrp.setEditable(false);
              con.close();
              stmt.close();
            }
//            catch(SQLException eM)
//            {
//            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"RECORD IS NOT FOUND ");
//            }
            catch(Exception et)
            {
                 et.printStackTrace();
              //  System.out.println("error:"+et.getMessage());
            }
```

help me please

Comment: Try using PreparedStatement to make update query.

Comment: not that this is the problem, but you don't want a where clause for that update statement? you will be updating all the rows.

Comment: Is this the first time you've encountered the said error with update? Try to update only one field then check if the same error will appear or try execute a hard-coded query. Also I prefer PreparedStatement as Shashank_Itmaster mentioned give it a try.

Comment: Can you print out the query being run and update it here.

Answer (score 1):

Is this a typo: "Residensial"?

```
... ResidensialAddress = '"+taraddr.getText()+"' ...
```

Answer (score 1):

to avoid sql-injection tru using the method PrepardStatment, it is easier to use and get the same results at the end.